# How to move s3 bucket data into Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

Since i am new to AWS platform and have requirement to write spark processed data into s3 and from s3 to redshift? would like to the best approach to move s3 data into redshift.? please share your thought on this.

Also i explored one of the option that spark processed data into redshift. one the discussion from stackoverflow, not recommeded to write spark to redshift directly.

COPY command from Redshift it will work. but it is manual process. once data reached the bucket , it should move the data to redshift automatically,

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654865/stream-data-from-s3-bucket-to-redshift-periodically

Comment: Thanks for the url.. the url mentioned that, we need to do COPY command from redshift.. looking for automatic and optimal solution.

Comment: Create a trigger on S3 bucket which will invoke Lambda function. From Lambda function you can easily execute SQL statement with COPY command. 
You can further add Step functions instead of monolithic Lambda and add orchestration in one simple DynamoDB table. Based on the output create notifications, and so on

Comment: target is redshift. need to copy TB of data froms s3 to  target systems...initially i though to implement via Lambda... noticed that,, Lambda will run only 15 min, if function execute take more time to execute , it will fail.. is that true

Comment: you don't have to wait in lambda. start the COPY command and exit. you can implement pooling to check when copy command is done and write status into your orchestrator record. Check STL_ tables for more information, from top of my mind STL_QUERY and STL_LOAD_ERRORS are what you need. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_intro_STL_tables.html